# Navigating Through Records From A Table

Tags: python-3.x

Using tkinter, i have created a form and 4 text-fields on it and there are 4 buttons that are used for navigating to records (First, Previous, Next, Last).
I have a table in MS Access with 4 columns and 5 rows.

I have connected python to MS access and on the screen the first record appears in each of the respective fields.

now, when i click on the "next" button, the next record should appear on the screen fields and when i click on the "previous" button the previous record of the table should appear on the screen.

Please help.

Thanks, Mukesh

i tried with .fetchall() or .fetchone() but that still shows 1 record or all records at a time.

**the code is**

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox


root = Tk()
root.title("My Personal Assistant - Phone Diary")


varName = StringVar()
varLandLine = StringVar()
varMobile = StringVar()
varImportant = IntVar()
def do_validations():
    if checkvar1.get() == 1:
        messagebox.showinfo("-Importance-","Yes, Its Important Contact")

def MakeAccessConnection():
    import pyodbc
    conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=J:\Python\PythonTest.mdb;')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('select * from PhoneDiary')
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        #print (row)
        varName.set(row[2])
        varLandLine.set(row[3])
        varMobile.set(row[4])
        varImportant.set(row[6])
```

cursor.fetchall() is fetching all records at a single time.. what i need is, it should fetch the first record (that i can do with cursor.fetchone()) but, now to move to the next record.

what method to use to navigate records of the cursor. - the screen is showing one record at a time only on click of the buttons will the data move to prior or next record?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
import pyodbc


conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\\your_path_here\\testdb.accdb;')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('select * from tracking_sales')


for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print (row)
```

Comment: I have tried this already, this will print ALL the records from the table on the command prompt.

Comment: I have tried this already, this will print ALL the records from the table on the command prompt.

What i am looking at is.. 

1) I have a GUI form with 4 text fields
2) in the GUI form, there are 4 buttons that are used to navigate records from the table.
3) there is a table with 4 fields and 5 records
4) now, i am able to see the first record from the 4 fields of table to 4 fields on the form.
5) MY REQUIREMENT IS - when i click on the NEXT button, the 2nd record from the table should show up in the form.